# How to access properties file using dynamic keys in react?

Tags: reactjs, key

Sample properties file.

```
const properties = {
    subproper: {
        name:'denise',
        age:'64'
     }
}
```

Accessing this in code base

subproper.name or subproper.age

What if I want to use dynamic keys?

eg: I tried these two, but both give the error

```
{subproper.$[`${this.state.propertie1}`] // $ is not a function
{subproper.$`${this.state.propertie1}`} //cannot call value1 of undefined (value1 is value of key this.state.propertie1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing keys using [`[]` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```
const props = {name:"Jon",surname:"Doe"}

const dynamicKey1 = "name";
const dynamicKey2 = "surname"

console.log(props[dynamicKey1]);
console.log(props[dynamicKey2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, replace dynamic with your property.

```js
const properties = { subproper: { name:'denise', age:'64' } }

const dynamic = "name";

console.log(properties.subproper[dynamic])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [ ] or use Object.values(Objectname)

example:`{subproper.[Objectname]}
or {subproper.[Object.values(objectname)[array_index]]}`